# SUM ROW NUMBER to get Volume for Fund and type of event

Tags: sql

1. What i need is to be able to sum row numbers as Volume column which act as a column which will sum the  duplicates for any fund.

```
drop table #temp1
SELECT [ID]
      ,[DateCreated]
      ,[Fund]
      ,[EventType]
      ,[CurrentResponsibility]
      ,[ShortDesc]
      ,[ETSDatabase]
      ,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by requestno ORDER BY requestno Asc)[ROWNUMBER]
      ,SUM(ROWNUMBER) over(partition by requestno ORDER BY requestno Asc)[Total]
  FROM  *Table*
   WHERE  datecreated   between '01JULY2020' and '30JUlY2020'

  GROUP BY DateCreated,Fund,EventType
  ORDER BY DATECREATED DESC
```

2.Sample Data

[image: 1]

3. Result

[image: 2]

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and tag with the database you are using.  Summing the row number doesn't actually make much sense.  You *could* calculate the cumulative sum easily that doesn't seem useful, except as a math exercise.

Comment: Added Pic for sample and Result table.

Answer (score 0):

from screenshots seems like you want this :

```
select FundName, EventType, Count(*) Volume
from *Table*
where datecreated between '01/07/2020' and '30/07/2020'
group by FundName, EventType
```

Comment: HI I did the exact way above but i am getting "Column 'DBO.ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Yes , the error message is clear . This query produce what you showed in the output , changing that change the solution. I recommande you ask a new question.